# Query with new and Distinct together

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Entity Book, a DTO and a Repository for this Class.

I'm trying to query all the results into the DTO I found this: `select new br.com.fall.controllers.dto.LivroDTO(l.name,l.page, l.publisher,l.cat1,l.cat2,l.cat3,l.launchDate) from Book l where l.name LIKE %?1`

But, I need eliminate books with repeated name, like something: `select distinct (name) new BookDTO ...`

Did someone know how to do this with @Query Annotation?
Or I need to filter this by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do sou by simply adding the `distinct` keyword:

```
select distinct new br.com.fall.controllers.dto.LivroDTO(l.name,l.page, l.publisher,l.cat1,l.cat2,l.cat3,l.launchDate) from Book l where l.name LIKE %?1
```

This distinct will apply to all fields, you cannot apply this to `name` only.

Comment: @KarenOliveira if you find books with same name and different publishers, which is the publisher you'll take?